# Polyglossia and toc

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, polyglossia

I'm using `xelatex`, with the package `polyglossia` (french).

I've got a problem with the formatting of the table of contents, using `xetex` and the package `polyglossia` (language: french). I don' manage to get the number of parts before the title ...

Here is an ECM to understand this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\XeTeXinputencoding iso-8859-1
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{latin}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part title}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{section title}
\part{another part}
\end{document}
```

With this code here is the appearance of the toc :

> Part title (without number ...) 1 chapter title
>
> 1.1. Section
>
> ...

And I would like this formatting :

> I. Title
>
> 1 Chapter title
>
> 1.1 Section title ...

What should I do to have the "I" enabled in the toc ? Can somebody help me ?
Thanks.

vangelis

Answer (score 2):

Polyglossia uses a ‘poor person's way’ to remove the part number from the part page: it simply redefines `\thepart` to produce nothing.

Here's a better way for the `book` class (other classes may need a different patch to `\@part`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{latin}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\makeatletter
% avoid the redefinition of `\thepart`
\patchcmd{\captionsfrench}{\def\thepart{}}{}{}{}
% patch \@part not to print the part number
\patchcmd{\@part}{\nobreakspace\thepart}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{Part title}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{section title}

\part{another part}

\end{document}
```

If you use

```
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\raggedleft\huge\fontfamily{ppl}}
  {\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
  {0pt}
  {}
```

for setting the part title, then the patch to `\@part` is useless and you can simply correct with

```
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\raggedleft\huge}
  {\MakeUppercase{\partname}}
  {0pt}
  {}
```

Of course `\fontfamily{ppl}` is completely useless in that position. There are two cases: you want to use Palatino for the part titles or not. If yes, then Palatino should be the main font of the document, so you don't need specifying `\fontfamily{ppl}`; if no, you again don't need it. On the other hand, if you don't follow the command with `\selectfont` it will do nothing.

Another *caveat*: avoid specifying `\XeTeXinputencoding`: save your documents as UTF-8 and your life will be better.

Comment: It seems to work for the table of contents.

Comment: Ok, I solve the problem by suppressing `\thepart` in the `titleformat` command : `\titleformat{\part} [display] {\raggedleft\huge\fontfamily{ppl}} {\MakeUppercase{\partname}} {0pt} {}% `Thanks again !