# Remove space before polyglossia's French parts in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, polyglossia

My question begins like this one: [Polyglossia and toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144383).

For some reason, the `french` option of `polyglossia` removes part numbers from the table of contents, leaving an ugly space in its wake. The question linked above asks for a way to add these numbers back, and it received a good but very complicated answer. I'm not asking for the same thing: I don't want the numbers back, I just want to remove that space, and I believe there is an easy way to do that.

Indeed, adding an `\unskip` in the argument of `\part` is sufficient to remove the unwanted horizontal space from the table of contents. See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{English part with a number}

\begin{french}

\part{French part with an ugly space}

\part{\unskip French part with nothing}

\end{french}
\end{document}
```

(The change of language between parts is only there to show the difference. My document will be in French only.)

Result:

[image: Table of contents example]

Now I just want to find a way to remove that space to all parts, without needing to add `\unskip` every time. I thought of a naive way:

```
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\part{\unskip #1}}
```

But when I try to compile, nothing happens, the compilation seems stuck.

So, what's the easiest way to get rid of that unwanted space in the table of contents?

Comment: As a side-note, I eventually found a quick but limited fix to my problem by adding `\let\oldpart\part` `\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\oldpart{\unskip #1}}`. However, egreg's answer is undoubtedly more appropriate, which is why I accepted it. I don't think my own fix would add much value if I posted it as a second answer, so I'm just mentioning it here, in case someone went through the same reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad design of the standard classes, but they’ve been like that for many years…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}
  {\thepart\hspace{1em}}
  {\partnumberline{\thepart}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\newrobustcmd{\partnumberline}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else #1\hspace{1em}\fi
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{English part with a number}

\begin{french}

\part{French part with nothing}

\end{french}
\end{document}
```

[image]